# Input output for 3d files

Tags: 3d-printing

How to work in Mathematica for export /import/view. Thanks for help.

EDIT1:

Export/import not working after rotations ( geometric Transformation) but was working before the transformation.

EDIT2:

A workaround with direct rotation works as below given but question remains how to work with *geometric Transformation*?

```
ClearAll;
a = 1.; ri = 0.166; smax = 1.3;
hel = {SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]]^2/(R[s] Sin[SI[s]]), 
   SI[0] == 1.45, PH'[s]/Cos[PH[s]] == -1/a, PH[0] == 0, 
   R'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], Z'[s] == Cos[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], 
   TH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], R[0] == ri, Z[0] == 0, TH[0] == 0};
NDSolve[hel, {SI, PH, R, TH, Z}, {s, 0, smax}];
{r[t_], th[t_], z[t_]} = {R[t], TH[t], Z[t]} /. First[%];
heli = First@
  ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s]], r[s] Sin[th[s]], z[s]}, {s, .0, 
    smax}, PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[.01]}]
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[heli, 
  Table[{RotationMatrix[a, {0, 0, 1}], {  0 Cos[a],  0 Sin[a], 
     0 a}}, {a, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/5}]], Boxed -> False]
 Export["helix.stl", %];
Import["helix.stl"] 
(* Works however, without GeometricTransformation *)
a = 1.; ri = 0.166; smax = 3; Rad = 0.1;
hel = {SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]]^2/(R[s] Sin[SI[s]]), 
   SI[0] == 1.45, PH'[s]/Cos[SI[s]] == -1/a, PH[0] == 0, 
   R'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], Z'[s] == Cos[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], 
   TH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], R[0] == ri, Z[0] == 0, TH[0] == 0};
NDSolve[hel, {SI, PH, R, TH, Z}, {s, 0, smax}];
{r[t_], th[t_], z[t_]} = {R[t], TH[t], Z[t]} /. First[%];
With[{Rad = 0.006}, 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s] + #], z[s], 
      r[s]  Sin[th[s] + #]}, {s, 0, smax}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Tube[Rad]}] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6], 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]]
Export["helix.stl", %];
Import["helix.stl"]
```

Comment: make the last two lines `Export["spiral.stl", %];` and `Import["spiral.stl"]` and it works. whats the question exactly?  ( "BinaryFormat" seems to be supported only for `Import` )

Comment: It works, minor errors corrected.

Comment: What is the point of ` + 0 v` and I think you have to remove the `;` at the end of the `NDSolve` and `Show`-lines for this to work. The resulting plot looks nice. Yellow and Gray combine really well with Mathematica's default colored 3D lighting setup!

Comment: Indeed good. I modified an earlier program but in rotating each spaghetti thing for multiple copies somewhere there is  flap. Shall be back after a while. Thanks.

Comment: @masterxilo the `%` grabs the last result regardless of the `;`